# header is not cleared after executing ob_get_clean

Tags: php

I have a php file  as the following :

```
<?php
ob_start();


header("Location:http://google.com");
echo "hello world";

die(ob_get_clean());

?>
```

I expect to see hello world on my browser,But It redirects to google.
ob_get_clean should clear the output including headers, Right?
And the result should be die("hello world"); 
So why is this happening?

Comment: _But It redirects to google..._ Of course it does...see `header(...)` this is what you want it to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, headers are not buffered. From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php):

> This function will turn output buffering on. While output buffering is active no output is sent from the script (**other than headers**), instead the output is stored in an internal buffer.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't know this after several years of programming!,Thank You

Answer (score 1):

```
header("Location:http://google.com");
```

It means page is redirected to google.com as buffer initiate.
Buffer is used to Store the Output data but in this case page is redirected to other site. So place of code is not correct.